# Best way of using hugging face's Mask Filling for more than 1 masked token at a time

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I am able to use hugging face's mask filling pipeline to predict 1 masked token in a sentence using the below:

```
!pip install -q transformers
from __future__ import print_function
import ipywidgets as widgets
from transformers import pipeline

nlp_fill = pipeline('fill-mask')
nlp_fill("I am going to guess <mask> in this sentence")
```

But does anyone have an opinion on what is the best way to do this if I want to predict 2 masked tokens? e.g. if the sentence is instead `"I am going to <mask> <mask> in this sentence"`?

If i try and put this exact sentence into nlp_fill I get the error `"ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars"` so it doesn't work automatically.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: sorry, didn't realise it was so important to give people upvotes

Comment: This may help https://ramsrigoutham.medium.com/sized-fill-in-the-blank-or-multi-mask-filling-with-roberta-and-huggingface-transformers-58eb9e7fb0c

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, the expectation that there be only one word behind the mask is [hardcoded into the FillMaskPipeline class](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/pipelines.html#FillMaskPipeline).

For a more constrained problem, of mask-filling *given a fixed number of choices to fill the mask*, it is possible to extend [FitBERT](https://github.com/Qordobacode/fitbert) to do this - I have a notebook I can send you if you message me, but it's embarassingly bad code. I am one of the authors of FitBERT, but I haven't had a chance to add this.

EDIT

[Here is the notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bBY8OcDz8zm6Ba4xZWjh-HqtUJET07nl) , don’t judge me

Comment: Not sure how to message you but yeah I’d love to see that notebook if possible?